# Import file where its column names different from the names in model caused rows with empty string

Tags: django, django-import-export

I would like to use django-import-export package to import some TSV files, but I'm facing some problems.

In the file, I have the column names in uppercase like this: INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE, TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT, TOTALREMAINING

In the model I have the same name but with lowercase and undersocre like so:

```py
class Offering(models.Model):
    industry_group_type = models.CharField(max_length=260)
    total_offering_amount = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    total_remaining = models.CharField(max_length=17)
```

The resource class look like this:

```py
class OfferingResource(ModelResource):
    industry_group_type = Field(attribute='INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE')
    total_offering_amount = Field(attribute='TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT')
    total_remaining = Field(attribute='TOTALREMAINING')

    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        fields = ('id', 'industry_group_type', 'total_offering_amount', 'total_remaining')
```

When the file is imported, empty rows are created that contain just empty string `''`, and there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I should use column names of the file as class attribute variable name, not as the value of the `attribute` argument of the `Field` class.

So, the resource class should be like this:

```py
class OfferingResource(ModelResource):
    INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE = Field(attribute='industry_group_type')
    TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT = Field(attribute='total_offering_amount')
    TOTALREMAINING = Field(attribute='total_remaining')

    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        fields = ('id', 'INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE', 'TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT', 'TOTALREMAINING')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, declaring the resource field to match the attribute name will work, but you can also use the `column_name` parameter to declare the field name in the tsv.  You can use 'attribute' to declare the corresponding attribute on your model object

```py
class OfferingResource(ModelResource):
    industry_group_type = Field(attribute='industry_group_type', column_name='INDUSTRYGROUPTYPE')
    total_offering_amount = Field(attribute='total_offering_amount', column_name='TOTALOFFERINGAMOUNT')
    total_remaining = Field(attribute='total_remaining', column_name='TOTALREMAINING')

    class Meta:
        model = Offering
        fields = ('id', 'industry_group_type', 'total_offering_amount', 'total_remaining')
```

[Docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#declaring-fields)